# Is it possible to pass properties from an .sln file to project file in MSBuild?

Tags: .net, msbuild

Consider the following snippet from an .sln file:

```
...
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MainApp", "MainApp\MainApp.csproj", "{FC66E4A5-0538-47DC-B450-788B98D9461E}"
EndProject
...
```

And the following snippet from the corresponding MainApp.csproj file:

```
...
<ItemGroup Condition="$(LibAProjRef) == false">
  <Reference Include="LibA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>..\..\Lib\LibA.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="$(LibAProjRef) == true">
  <ProjectReference Include="..\LibA\LibA.csproj">
    <Project>{2A45F32B-182B-4B8D-A8A4-1BFBF2E81CAD}</Project>
    <Name>LibA</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
...
```

Basically what I'm trying to do here is create a project file that can use another library project, either already built, or as a project reference, depending on if the library project is present in the solution or not.

Is there a way to pass properties from the .sln file to the project file so that I can accomplish this?

Or: is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass properties from the .sln file, because MSBuild actually works with XML files!

What I could think of is to write a Custom MSBuild Task, and read the wanted values from the .sln file.

Comment: How would the custom task know which solution it is running from?

Comment: When building a sln (msbuild or vstudio), these predefined macros are available: SolutionDir, SolutionExt, SolutionFileName, SolutionName, SolutionPath. You can easily find these by building any sln using msbuild with verbosity 'detailed'.

Answer (score 0):

You can repurpose either the Configuration or Platform properties, which can be set in a dropdown of the solution, or use one of the properties Scott Bilas mentioned.

I was hijacking the $(Configuration) field, but now thanks to Scott's comment:

```
<ProjectReference Include="$(SolutionDir)\..\DataLib\DataLib.csproj">
```

I'm guessing you could go either way, and your use of conditions appears sound.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need for a post-build event. I used the following solution in VS2015.

You can define your Property in MainApp.csproj inside the PropertyGroup tag like so:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
        <LibAProjRef>False</LibAProjRef>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and then when you build the solution you can say

```
MSBuild "MySln.sln" /m /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /p:LibAProjRef=True
```

Note that the here the Properties are strings so your condition should be

```
Condition="'$(LibAProjRef)' == 'True'"
```